# Remove Redbar while application is in backgroung and allowing VOIP notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, voip, background-service

Red bar is displaying on top of device screen while I am receiving any VOIP notifications. In didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload method, I am doing nothing no microphone operations, No GPS, no audio session nothing at all just core data operations.

This red bar is indicating VOIP background use but I want to remove this red bar from top of screen without disabling VOIP from build settings.

I don't have any idea how to remove this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have similar issue... please answer if you find any solution to this...

Comment: That Red bar is an indication that an app is recording the microphone in background, it can be a voip app or voice recorder app internally invoked AVAuidoSession.
Try Callkit, it will show green bar instead of red, like real PSTN call :)